# How to transform a cube root of a fraction into an fraction without cube root in the denominator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, root, cube, python-fractions

How do I write a python def function that can take the cube roots of fractions and return the answer as a fraction as a coefficient with a cube root in the numerator only? I am new to coding, so I apologize if my question sounds vague. I am trying to write a program that can solve any cubic equation and return that answer in its exact form. Currently, I have a program that can do this, but it only gives the roots as a decimal.

For example, I want the answers of:

**This** ∛10 / ∛56 = ∛490/14
      **Not**  ∛10 / ∛56 = 0.56312394

**This** ∛1 / ∛27 = 1/3
      **Not** ∛1 / ∛27 = 0.333333333

**This** ∛48 / ∛9 = 6∛18/9
      **Not** ∛48 / ∛9 = 1.74716092

Basically, I just need -cubic_root(c) to be return as a fraction instead of a decimal

```
def cubic_root(x): 
        '''Compute cubic root of a number while maintaining its sign'''
        if x >= 0:
            return x**third #x**third means x^3
        else:
            return -(-x)**third

    if f == g == h == 0:
        x1 = -cubic_root(c) # I need this in fraction form
```

This is the entire code

```
'''
Cubic Equation Calculator (Exact Form)
By Patrick Thomas
'''

import time
import math
import fractions
goAgain = True

time.sleep(0.5)
print('')
print('Cubic Equation Calculator (Exact Form)')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('A Patman Inc. Program')

#While Loop---------------------------------------------------------------------
while goAgain == True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('--------------------------')
    print('ax³ + bx² + cx + d = 0')
    print('--------------------------')
    
    a = int(input('a = '))
    
    b = int(input('b = '))
    
    c = int(input('c = '))
    
    d = int(input('d = '))
    
    print('')
    
#Math---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a0 = b/a
    b0 = c/a
    c0 = d/a
    #a0 Fraction--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def a0(b,a):
        if int(a) == 0:
            return int(b)
        return a0(int(a), int(b) % int(a))
    a0_GCD = a0(b,a)
    b_Simp = int(b) / a0_GCD
    a_Simp = int(a) / a0_GCD
    a0_frac = fractions.Fraction(int(b_Simp),int(a_Simp))
    print('a0 = {}'.format(a0_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    #b0 Fraction--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def b0(c,a):
        if int(a) == 0:
            return int(c)
        return b0(int(a), int(c) % int(a))
    b0_GCD = b0(c,a)
    c_Simp = int(c) / b0_GCD
    a_Simp = int(a) / b0_GCD
    b0_frac = fractions.Fraction(int(c_Simp),int(a_Simp))
    print('b0 = {}'.format(b0_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    #c0 Fraction--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def c0(d,a):
        if int(a) == 0:
            return int(d)
        return b0(int(a), int(d) % int(a))
    c0_GCD = c0(d,a)
    d_Simp = int(d) / b0_GCD
    a_Simp = int(a) / b0_GCD
    c0_frac = fractions.Fraction(int(d_Simp),int(a_Simp))
    print('c0 = {}'.format(c0_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    a0 = b/a
    b0 = c/a
    c0 = d/a
    
    a = a0
    b = b0
    c = c0
    
    # Some repeating constants and variables
    third = 1./3. #Cube root
    a13 = a*third #a is divided by 3
    a13_num = int(b_Simp) * 1 
    a13_den = int(a_Simp) * 3
    a13_frac = fractions.Fraction(a13_num,a13_den)
    print('') #remove when finished
    print('a13 (decimal) = {}'.format(a13)) #remove when finished
    print('a13 (fraction) = {}'.format(a13_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    a2 = a13*a13 #quotient of a*third times quotient of a*third
    a2_num = a13_num * a13_num
    a2_den = a13_den * a13_den
    a2_frac = fractions.Fraction(int(a2_num),int(a2_den))
    print('') #remove when finished
    print('a2 (decimal) = {}'.format(a2)) #remove when finished
    print('a2 (fraction) = {}'.format(a2_frac)) #remove when finished
    sqr3 = math.sqrt(3)
    
    # Additional intermediate variables
    
    #f--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    f = third * b - a2
    thirdb_num = 1 * int(c_Simp) 
    thirdb_den = 3 * int(a_Simp)
    thirdb = fractions.Fraction(thirdb_num,thirdb_den)
    f_frac = thirdb - a2_frac
    
    print('') #remove when finished
    print('f (decimal) = {}'.format(f)) #remove when finished
    print('f (fraction) = {}'.format(f_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    #g--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    g = a13 * (2*a2 - b) + c
    paren = 2*a2 - b
    two_a2_num = 2 * a2_num
    two_a2_den = 1 * a2_den
    two_a2_frac = fractions.Fraction(int(two_a2_num),int(two_a2_den))
    parenthesis = two_a2_frac - b0_frac
    g_frac = a13_frac * parenthesis + c0_frac
    
    print('') #remove when finished
    print('g (decimal) = {}'.format(g)) #remove when finished
    print('g (fraction) = {}'.format(g_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    #h--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    h = 0.25*g*g + f*f*f
    one_forth = fractions.Fraction(int(1),int(4))
    h_frac = one_forth * g_frac * g_frac + f_frac * f_frac * f_frac
    print('') #remove when finished
    print('h (decimal) = {}'.format(h)) #remove when finished
    print('h (fraction) = {}'.format(h_frac)) #remove when finished
    
    #cubic_root(x)--------------------------------------------------------------
    def cubic_root(x): 
        '''Compute cubic root of a number while maintaining its sign'''
        if x >= 0:
            return x**third #x**third means x^3
        else:
            return -(-x)**third

    if f == g == h == 0:
        x1 = -cubic_root(c) # I need this in fraction form
        print('x₁ = {:.5f}'.format(x1))
        print('x₂ = {:.5f}'.format(x1))
        print('x₃ = {:.5f}'.format(x1))

    elif h <= 0:
        j = math.sqrt(-f)
        k = math.acos(-0.5*g / (j*j*j))
        m = math.cos(third*k)
        n = sqr3 * math.sin(third*k)
        x1 = 2*j*m - a13
        x2 = -j * (m + n) - a13
        x3 = -j * (m - n) - a13
        print('x₁ = {:.5f}'.format(x1))
        print('x₂ = {:.5f}'.format(x2))
        print('x₃ = {:.5f}'.format(x3))

    else:
        sqrt_h = math.sqrt(h)
        S = cubic_root(-0.5*g + sqrt_h)
        U = cubic_root(-0.5*g - sqrt_h)
        S_plus_U = S + U
        S_minus_U = S - U
        x1 = S_plus_U - a13
        x2 = -0.5*S_plus_U - a13 + S_minus_U*sqr3*0.5j
        x3 = -0.5*S_plus_U - a13 - S_minus_U*sqr3*0.5j
        
    #x1 Section-----------------------------------------------------------------
        print('') #remove when finished
        print('x₁ = {:.5f}'.format(float(x1)))
        
    #x2 Section-----------------------------------------------------------------
    x2_str = str(x2)
    
    if '+' in x2_str:
        x2_part1, x2_part2 = x2_str.split('+')
        x2_part1 = x2_part1.replace('(','')
        x2_part2 = x2_part2.replace('j)','')
        x2_part1_num = float(x2_part1)
        x2_part2_num = float(x2_part2)
        if float(x2_part2_num) == 0:
            print('x₂ = {:.5f}'.format(x2_part1_num))
        else:
            print('x₂ = {:.5f} + {:.5f}i'.format(x2_part1_num,x2_part2_num))
        
    elif '-' in x2_str:
        if '(-' in x2_str:
            x2_str = x2_str.replace('(-','')
            x2_part1, x2_part2 = x2_str.split('-')
            x2_part1 = x2_part1.replace('','-',1)
            x2_part1 = x2_part1.replace('(','')
            x2_part2 = x2_part2.replace('j)','')
            x2_part1_num = float(x2_part1)
            x2_part2_num = float(x2_part2)
            if float(x2_part2_num) == 0:
                print('x₂ = {:.5f}'.format(x2_part1_num))
            else:
                print('x₂ = {:.5f} - {:.5f}i'.format(x2_part1_num,x2_part2_num))
        else:
            x2_part1, x2_part2 = x2_str.split('-')
            x2_part1 = x2_part1.replace('(','')
            x2_part2 = x2_part2.replace('j)','')
            x2_part1_num = float(x2_part1)
            x2_part2_num = float(x2_part2)
            if float(x2_part2_num) == 0:
                 print('x₂ = {:.5f}'.format(x2_part1_num))
            else:
                print('x₂ = {:.5f} - {:.5f}i'.format(x2_part1_num,x2_part2_num))
            
    #x3 Section-----------------------------------------------------------------
    x3_str = str(x3)
    
    if '+' in x3_str:
        x3_part1, x3_part2 = x3_str.split('+')
        x3_part1 = x3_part1.replace('(','')
        x3_part2 = x3_part2.replace('j)','')
        x3_part1_num = float(x3_part1)
        x3_part2_num = float(x3_part2)
        if float(x3_part2_num) == 0:
            print('x₃ = {:.5f}'.format(x3_part1_num))
        else:
            print('x₃ = {:.5f} + {:.5f}i'.format(x3_part1_num,x3_part2_num))
        
    elif '-' in x3_str:
        if '(-' in x3_str:
            x3_str = x3_str.replace('(-','')
            x3_part1, x3_part2 = x3_str.split('-')
            x3_part1 = x3_part1.replace('','-',1)
            x3_part1 = x3_part1.replace('(','')
            x3_part2 = x3_part2.replace('j)','')
            x3_part1_num = float(x3_part1)
            x3_part2_num = float(x3_part2)
            if float(x3_part2_num) == 0:
                print('x₃ = {:.5f}'.format(x3_part1_num))
            else:
                print('x₃ = {:.5f} - {:.5f}i'.format(x3_part1_num,x3_part2_num))
        else:
            x3_part1, x3_part2 = x3_str.split('-')
            x3_part1 = x3_part1.replace('(','')
            x3_part2 = x3_part2.replace('j)','')
            x3_part1_num = float(x3_part1)
            x3_part2_num = float(x3_part2)
            if float(x3_part2_num) == 0:
                print('x₃ = {:.5f}'.format(x3_part1_num))
            else:
                print('x₃ = {:.5f} - {:.5f}i'.format(x3_part1_num,x3_part2_num))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the cube root in the denominator, we can multiply both numerator and denominator with the square of that cube root. For example:

∛48 / ∛9 = ∛48∛9² / ∛9∛9² = ∛(48⋅9²) / 9

Then a factor should be extracted from the cube root that is a cube. For that purpose we could find all factors and then identify those that have a power of 3 or more. The powers of 3 can be extracted out of the cube root. We can either code this ourselves, or make use of [`sympy.ntheory.factor_.core`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.core) with `t=3`, which extracts the cube-free factor, so that we can derive what the cube factor is.

In the example, we can write the fraction as:

∛(48⋅9²) / 9 = ∛(6³18) / 9 = 6∛18 / 9

The `core` function will give us the 18 from 48⋅9², and from the remaining factor 6³ (which always is a perfect cube) we can derive 6.

And then finally we can divide both the coefficient part of the numerator and the denominator by their greatest common divisor (which `Fraction` will do for us), and so we get:

6∛18 / 9 = 2∛18 / 3

```
from fractions import Fraction
from sympy.ntheory.factor_ import core  # for getting the cube free factor
from sympy import integer_nthroot  # for applying the integer cube-root

def rationalize(root3numerator, root3denominator):
    root3numerator *= root3denominator * root3denominator
    cubefree = core(root3numerator, t=3)
    cube,_ = integer_nthroot(root3numerator // cubefree, 3)
    return (Fraction(cube, root3denominator), cubefree)

# Helper function for formatting output
def format(fraction, root3):
    strdenominator = "" if fraction.denominator == 1 else f"/{fraction.denominator}"
    strroot3 = "" if root3 == 1 else f"∛{root3}"
    strcoefficient = "" if fraction.numerator == 1 and strroot3 else str(fraction.numerator)
    return f"{(fraction, root3)}: {strcoefficient}{strroot3}{strdenominator}"

# Example runs
for num, denom in [(10, 56), (1, 27), (48, 9), (20, 2)]:
    print((num, denom), "=>", format(*rationalize(num, denom)))
```

Comment: This works great! However, when I try to do ³⎷16 / ³⎷3, I get (144,3) when I should get 2 ³⎷18 / 3. Is there a way to modify this to make it return the correct answer?

Comment: Sure, but then the output should consist of three numbers. Would be good if your question had such specification.

Comment: OK, I edited your question for you. I updated my answer, which now returns 3 numbers: two in the form of a Fraction (numerator, denominator) and one number that needs the cube-root applied to it.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm new to coding so I'm sorry if I'm not very specific when it comes to questions. I am currently majoring in computer science after taking a coding class last fall and I fell in love with it. Right now I trying to get my gen eds out of the way so I can take more coding and software classes.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to write a program that can solve any cubic equation and return that answer in its exact form. Every cubic equation calculator that I have seen only returns the answer in decimal notation. Personally, I hate decimals because they are often irrational and I want the exact answer. Plus I am trying to challenge myself with something sophisticated. I wrote a quadratic equation calculator that can return the answer in its exact form and provide the same equation in vertex form, the axis of sym, y-int, and the vertex.

Comment: I will provide the quadratic equation calculator, the cubic equation calculator that can only give the answer in decimal notation, and the cubic equation calculator, which I am working on currently that can give the answer in its exact form.

Comment: My quadratic equation calculator is too long to post on Stack Overflow so I have copied the code to a Google Doc and have made the link public in case you are interested. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mYa9dBjdbVUAMSoNBK_9MiCkFi3631BTwL5qPX5IADU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more clear about what you want to achieve but here is an answer based on what I could understand from your question:

You need to look into the [Fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module. Here is script that does what you explained in your second example.

```
from fractions import Fraction

def cuberoot(number: float) -> float:
    if number < 0:
        number = abs(number)
        cube_root = number**(1/3)*(-1)
    else:
        cube_root = number**(1/3)
    return cube_root

def cube_root_fraction(initial_fraction: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    numerator = int(cuberoot(initial_fraction.numerator))
    denominator =  int(cuberoot(initial_fraction.denominator))
    return Fraction(numerator, denominator)
 
initial_fraction = Fraction(1, 27)
result = cube_root_fraction(initial_fraction)
print(result)
```

#### Input:

```
Fraction(1, 27)
```

#### Output:

```
1/3
```